# Finding the intervals of increase and decrease of $\frac{x^4 - x^3 -8}{x^2 - x - 6}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, monotone-functions

How can I find the intervals of increase and decrease of $\frac{x^4 - x^3 -8}{x^2 - x - 6}$?

I tried to find the derivative by the quotient rule to obtain the critical points but the formula was getting complicated, I know that $D_f = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-2,3\}$  but then what?

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: First see the answer of Hector Blandin.  Assuming that this problem is from a book or class, I would not expect the problem composer to intend that you be forced to confront a $5$th degree polynomial with no rational roots.  That is, what would the educational value in such a problem be?  I verified the computation of the numerator in Hector Blandin's answer.  Therefore, I can't help but wonder if there is a typo in the problem that you have presented.  I wonder if you have made a mistake, either in the numerator or the denominator.

Comment: If the denominator were $x^2 + x - 6$, a factor of $x - 2$ could be canceled from the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 2):

One can simplify calculation of derivative by partitioning fraction:

$$\frac{x^4 - x^3 -8}{x^2 - x - 6}=Ax^2+Bx+C+\frac{D}{x-3}+\frac{E}{x+2}$$

$$\frac{x^4 - x^3 -8}{x^2 - x - 6}=x^2+6+\frac{46}{5(x-3)}-\frac{16}{5(x+2)}$$

$$\left(\frac{x^4 - x^3 -8}{x^2 - x - 6}\right)'=2x-\frac{46}{5(x-3)^2}+\frac{16}{5(x+2)^2}$$

Unfortunately, for this problem one needs to have common denominator, which makes almost no sense in proposed way of calculation. Common denominator is $5(x-3)^2(x+2)^2$ and numerator is $$2x(x-3)^2(x+2)^2-46(x+2)^2+16(x-3)^2=2(x^5-2x^4-11x^3+9x^2+8x-4)$$ Then getting answer requires solving fifth degree algebraic equation, which I suppose cannot be done in closed-form.

If there is typo error in some one of signs before $x^3$ or $x$ in problem, then this way of solution leads to cubic equation.

Answer (score 1):

The sign of the derivative of $\frac{x^4 - x^3 -8}{x^2 - x - 6}$ is exactly the same sign of $-4+8x+9x^2-11x^3-2x^4+x^5$. This polynomial has no rational roots:

[image]